# Conditional format if one cell is filled and another is an error

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, formula

I have this workbook set up with two formula driven columns.  Rather than seeing #N/A if column B is not filled, however, I have it appear blank.  I am trying to conditional format Column A to turn red if Column B has a value, yet column A is technically error.

The formula I have been trying to get to work is this, but it isn't functioning.
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPHS4.jpg)

=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B:B)),ISERROR(A:A))

Answer (score 0):

I think two things are going on here:

First, this doesn't work because you are referencing ranges:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B:B)),ISERROR(A:A))
```

With your mouse or keyboard, manually select the range A2:A100 (or whatever the last row is). Add a conditional formatting rule using cell references like this:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)),ISERROR(A2))
```

A little explanation on relative references in conditional formatting.. When you select a range of cells and apply conditional formatting, it checks the references' positions relative to the top left cell you had selected, then applies those relative positions to the other cells highlighted. So in this case the top left cell is A2, so for all cells, it will consider the cell it self for ISERROR, and the cell to the right for ISBLANK. If that doesn't make sense, ask in the comments and maybe someone can explain it better.

Second, if you have "handled" your error in the A column so that #N/A doesn't show, like if A2 looks something like this: '=IF(ISERROR(function(B2)),"",function(B2))', then the conditional formatting rule won't trigger on ISERROR(A2) since A2 does not resolve to an error. You would have to put the actual function in the conditional formatting formula which evaluates to an error. Something like this:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)),ISERROR(function(B2)))
```

I'm not sure if that's what is going on, but you had mentioned that you make column A appear blank, so it sounds like you are handling the error within the A column. Instead of handling the error in column A, you could just let column A resolve to the error and then turn both the text and the cell color to red in the conditional formatting rule to hide the error text. Just throwing that out there.

Hopefully I understood the question. If not then please let me know so I can update the solution.